# utf8 library in Lua 5.3 incorrect encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, lua

I have an input string "pythön!"

If I do the utf8 encoding online [here](https://mothereff.in/utf-8) I get:

\x70\x79\x74\x68\xC3\xB6\x6E\x21

if I make it a string and print it:

```
print("\x70\x79\x74\x68\xC3\xB6\x6E\x21")
```

I get: pyth├╢n!

When I do utf8 encoding using the utf8 library in Lua like:

```
c = b:gsub(".",function(s) print(s) return utf8.char(s:byte()) end)
```

print(c) prints out: pyth┬ön!

Why are these 2 different? Also I checked codes for c:

```
for p,c in utf8.codes(c) do print(p,string.format("%X",c)) end
```

Which returns:

```
1       70
2       79
3       74
4       68
5       94
7       6E
8       21
```

The code #5 is different and #6 is missing. Why is that happening?

Comment: `gsub(".")` and `s:byte()` work with 1-byte encodings only.  They do not work with Unicode texts.

Comment: Got it! Which library can get me the right utf8 encoding in Lua?